# protocol method is not being called by the delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, delegates

I have implemented protocol in my app,

I have declared protocol method in `loginViewController` and i am calling `protocolMethod` from `confirmViewController`

Here is my code snippet:
**`loginViewController.h`**

```
@protocol FirstControllerDelegate<NSObject>
@required
-(void)protocolMethod;

@end

@interface loginViewController : UIViewController<FirstControllerDelegate>

@end
```

**`loginViewController.m`**

```
- (IBAction)loginBtnClicked:(id)sender {
    confirmViewController *obj = [confirmViewController new];
     obj.delegate=self;
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"confirmloginsegue" sender:self];


}

-(void)protocolMethod{
    NSLog(@"--- This is not callled ---");
     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Code for 
**`confirmViewController.h`**

```
@interface confirmViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <FirstControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

**`confirmViewController.m`**

```
 (IBAction)continueClicked:(id)sender {

    [_delegate protocolMethod]; //Calling protocol method...
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Where i am doing mistake?

**Please help and thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Wrong Approach and delegate initialisation

In this lines:-

```
confirmViewController *obj = [confirmViewController new];
     obj.delegate=self;
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"confirmloginsegue" sender:self];    

--- You are loosing the object here
```

### Solution

In your attribute inspector give the identifier for that confirmViewController, now push the vc and set the delegate for the object confirmViewController like this:-

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
ConfirmViewController *confirmViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ConfirmViewController"];

confirmViewController.delegate=self;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:confirmViewController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

The delegating class does not exist for long enough to matter:

```
- (IBAction)loginBtnClicked:(id)sender {
    confirmViewController *obj = [confirmViewController new];
    obj.delegate=self;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"confirmloginsegue" sender:self];
    // obj is destroyed here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `prepareForSegue` and set `delegate` there e.g.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    confirmViewController *destViewController = (confirmViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    destViewController.delegate=self;
}
```

for further detail check this link:- http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/

Answer (score 0):

You have to set delegate there. please,make some correction in your code like:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
confirmViewController *destViewController = (confirmViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
destViewController.delegate=self;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You shoul use `preparefrosegue` to set your delegate object. so your code should be like this,

```
- (IBAction)loginBtnClicked:(id)sender {

   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"confirmloginsegue" sender:self];
  }

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

confirmViewController *obj = [confirmViewController new];

//or

confirmViewController *obj = [segue destinationViewController];

obj.delegate=self;
}
```

hope this will help ;)

Answer (score 0):

If u are using View controller

```
SettingsHubViewController *settingVC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourStoryBoardIdentifier"];

settingVC.delegate = self;
```

If u are using XIB load the NIB after that set the `settingVC.delegate = self;`

its working for me (I created OverLay view and loaded in main class)